# Reload individual input with JS

Tags: javascript, input, reload

I'd like to refresh an input field every second while leaving the rest of the page untouched. Is there a way to do this with Javascript? I'm a little unsure how to write it, but I think it would look like..

```js
var myVar;

function autoRefresh() {
  myVar = setInterval(loadValue, 1000);
}

function loadValue() {
  input.reload("reload").value
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="reload">
```

I'm sure the syntax is wrong, but any input would be great!

Comment: Where are you getting the "refreshed" value from?

Comment: Why are you refreshing the value? Wouldn't it make more sense to just disable the input ?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but what should the field's value be when it is refreshed?

In this example, I'm turning the field into a clock by refreshing its value with the current time every second:

```js
document.getElementById("loadTime").textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

var input = document.getElementById("reload");

setInterval(function(){
  input.value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>Time page was loaded: <span id="loadTime"></span></div>
Current Time:<input type="text" id="reload">
```

Comment: The value for input field is a shortcode that links to a php function to return unix microtime

Comment: @ Got it. Please up vote and mark this answer as "the" answer if it does what you need.

Comment: Can I drop a shortcode (or the original php function) into this function as input.value? @Scott Marcus

Comment: @PhysicsIsRelativelyCool You can set `input.value =` to anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myVar;
var counter = 1;
var input = document.getElementById('reload');

function autoRefresh() {
  myVar = setInterval(loadValue, 1000);
}

function loadValue() {
  input.value = counter++;
}

autoRefresh();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="reload">
```

Comment: Good code, works quite nicely. Can I set the input.value to a shortcode?

Comment: This will scan the DOM for the input element every second. That code should not be in the callback.

Comment: @PhysicsIsRelativelyCool What does this shortcode means?